# Debug PowerPoint VSTO Add-In with opening a file by default

Tags: c#, debugging, vsto, powerpoint, command-line-arguments

In my PPT Add-In there is a bug where I don't run some initialization properly when you double-click a PPT file. This initialization is enabling certain button on the ribbon and should be done when the first presentation is opened (and the buttons are disabled when the last presentation is closed).

I can also reproduce the issue if I open `POWERPNT.EXE` with `/O FileName` arguments.

What I cannot do is start debugging with these command line arguments, since the Command line arguments I can set in the project settings does not seem to be delegated to `POWERPNT.EXE`.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to fall back to phpesque debugging (a.k.a logging to console)?

Comment: So in the properties of your Project in the tab debug you did set to "Start external program" and specified the "Command line arguments" and this doesnt work?

Comment: @RandRandom The start action was "Start project" by default. On switching to "Start external program" the arguments are properly registered and I can debug. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug your VSTO Add-in by using a different version of Office (2013 or 2016), open the `Project Designer`, and in the `Debug` tab, choose the `Start external program` option button. Then, browse to the location of the appropriate Office application executable. There also you can specify your command line arguments for the Office application. See [Debugging Office Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: It clearly states this under [Command line arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3) you are right

Answer (score 1):

To pass the commandline arguments as desired you have to switch to "Start external program" under

Project Properties --> Tab "Debug" --> Section "Start action"

Than use the "Browse" button to fill in the desired external program you wish to start, in this case the path to Power Point, or just type/paste it.

Then fill in the command line arguments in the text box below.

[image]

**Note**

This is only necessary when working with AddIn Projects, since their start routine differs from "normal" Window/Console Application. With those the "Start project" will respect the command line arguments correctly.

The AddIn Projects have something like this in their Project files:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{xxxxx}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="PowerPoint" HostPackage="{xxxxx}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="PowerPoint" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#POWERPNT.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/x" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
        <Host Name="PowerPoint" GeneratedCodeNamespace="PowerPointAddIn" IconIndex="0">
          <HostItem Name="ThisAddIn" Code="ThisAddIn.cs" CanonicalName="AddIn" CanActivate="false" IconIndex="1" Blueprint="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml" GeneratedCode="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs" />
        </Host>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

You could pass your desired command line Arguments to this value `DebugInfoCommandLine="/x"` and than those will be passed when using "Start project".